# Spike in Disk I/O due to external process causing PostgreSQL commits to pile up in the slow log

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, performance-tuning

**Background:**

I have a live Django app that utilizes 4 Redis instances alongwith PostgreSQL 9.6.5.

Note that the first two Redis instances are big in size: back ups amount to ~2GB and ~4.4GB respectively.

---

**The problem:**

PG data and Redis backups are both saved in the secondary drive `xvdb`.

I've noticed that whenever my big Redis instances start backing up, disk I/O naturally spikes and PostgreSQL commit statements start piling up in the slow log. Behold:

```
21:49:26.171 UTC [44861] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 3063.262 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44890] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 748.307 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44882] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 1497.461 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44893] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 655.063 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.171 UTC [44894] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 559.743 ms  statement: COMMIT
21:49:26.172 UTC [44883] ubuntu@myapp LOG:  duration: 1415.733 ms  statement: COMMIT
```

As a consequence, this is how my PostgreSQL commits look like every day:

[image]

---

**The question:**

Is there anything I can do on the PostgreSQL side to help smoothe out this spikey situation?

I'd like Redis and PostgreSQL to live in as much harmony as they possibly can on a single machine. If you feel this situation can only be helped from the Redis side, write that as an answer and I'll accept that too.

---

**More information:**

Ask for more information if you need it.

Machine specs:

```
AWS EC2 m4.4xlarge (16 cores, 64GB RAM)
Elastic Block Store gp2 volumes (105 IOPS, burst upto 3000 IOPS)
```

`redis-server --version` yields `Redis server v=4.0.2 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-4.0.3 bits=64 build=401ce53d7b0383ca`.

Typical `iostat -xmt 3` values are:

```
10/15/2017 08:28:35 PM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10.44    0.00    0.93    0.15    0.06   88.43

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    2.00     0.00     0.04    38.67     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     2.67    0.00   44.67     0.00     0.41    18.99     0.13    2.81    0.00    2.81   1.07   4.80
```

Compare that to the same around the time slow commits are logged:

```
10/15/2017 10:18:11 PM

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.16    0.00    0.65   11.90    0.04   79.24

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     4.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     0.02    48.00     0.00    1.33    0.00    1.33   1.33   0.13
xvdb              0.00     0.00    1.67 1312.00     0.01   163.50   254.90   142.56  107.64   25.60  107.75   0.76 100.00
```

If needed, here are some relevant lines from postgresql.conf:

```
shared_buffers = 2GB  
checkpoint_timeout = 30min              # range 30s-1d
max_wal_size = 2GB
min_wal_size = 700MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9      # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
#checkpoint_flush_after = 256kB         # measured in pages, 0 disables
#checkpoint_warning = 30s               # 0 disables
```

*Note: I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870538/optimizing-disk-i-o-when-running-redis-and-postgresql-on-a-single-machine) - but focused on Redis - separately on SO as well.*

Comment: If the delayed commits are a problem, I'd definitely move either Redis or Postgres onto its own host.  It's much easier to manage them separately than trying to recocile them.

Comment: What's on xvda?  Also, what filesystem is being used?

Comment: @jjanes: xvda houses the OS, webserver and logs etc. The filesystem is `ext4`.

Comment: Could you try moving pg_xlog to xvda, if it is big enough?

Comment: @jjanes: Yea I suppose I'll do that, or rather how about the redis instances? My postgresql DB is larger than my redis instances, and xvda is smaller than xvdb (35GB vs 175 GB)

Comment: I don't need to move your  entire postgresql data directory, just the pg_xlog subdirectory.  But moving it all would work.  Or just doing the backup over the network to a different machine.

Comment: @jjanes: Could you shed light on how moving solely `pg_xlog` to xvda would alleviate the symptoms? I only know superficially about it, that it contains write ahead logs.

Comment: Your complaint is specifically about COMMIT being slow.  That needs to write and sync to pg_xlog.  When a drive gets congested from unrelated activity, these syncs start to slow down.  If writes to other directories were also causing you problems, they would manifest in more than just COMMIT being slow.

Comment: @jjanes: that's quite incisive. Could you write that explanation (and your recommendation) as an answer as well?